# Why do I have duplicate records in my JOIN

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, reporting-services

I am retrieving data from table `ProductionReportMetrics` where I have column `NetRate_QuoteID`. Then to that result set I need to get `Description` column.

And in order to get a `Description` column, I need to join 3 tables:

- NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote
- NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote_Locat
- NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote_Locat_Liabi

But after that my premium is completely off.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
SELECT QLL.Description,
       QLL.ClassCode,
       prm.NetRate_QuoteID,
       QL.LocationID,
       ISNULL(SUM(premium),0) AS NetWrittenPremium,
       MONTH(prm.EffectiveDate) AS EffMonth
FROM ProductionReportMetrics prm    
LEFT JOIN NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote Q
    ON prm.NetRate_QuoteID = Q.QuoteID
INNER JOIN NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote_Locat QL
    ON Q.QuoteID = QL.QuoteID
INNER JOIN NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote_Locat_Liabi QLL
    ON QL.LocationID = QLL.LocationID       
WHERE YEAR(prm.EffectiveDate) = 2016 AND
      CompanyLine = 'Ironshore Insurance Company' 
GROUP BY MONTH(prm.EffectiveDate),
         QLL.Description,
         QLL.ClassCode,
         prm.NetRate_QuoteID,
         QL.LocationID
```

[image]

[image]

I think the problem in this table:
[image]

What Am I missing in this Query?

```
select 
        ClassCode,
        QLL.Description,
        sum(Premium)

from    ProductionReportMetrics prm
LEFT JOIN  NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote Q ON prm.NetRate_QuoteID = Q.QuoteID
LEFT JOIN NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote_Locat QL ON Q.QuoteID = QL.QuoteID  
LEFT JOIN
            (SELECT * FROM NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote_Locat_Liabi nqI 
                JOIN ( SELECT LocationID, MAX(ClassCode) 
                FROM NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote_Locat_Liabi GROUP BY LocationID ) nqA 
                    ON nqA.LocationID = nqI.LocationID ) QLL ON QLL.LocationID = QL.LocationID  
where   Year(prm.EffectiveDate) = 2016 AND CompanyLine = 'Ironshore Insurance Company' 
GROUP BY Q.QuoteID,QL.QuoteID,QL.LocationID
```

Now it says

```
Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
The column 'LocationID' was specified multiple times for 'QLL'.
```

[image]

Comment: A few questions: Why did you use the LEFT JOIN on the first join? What tables do your columns premium, CompanyLine belong to?

Comment: There are no duplicates, anywhere, in this example result set.  If you want, for example, for there to be only one record with `Contractors - Executive Supervisors, 91580+`, then you will have to somehow aggregate the other columns from these records (e.g. using the average, max, min, etc.).

Comment: I used LEFT JOIN because I want to keep the result from ProductionReportMetrics table and then, to that result I want to add ClassCode Description column. So, according to  LEFT JOIN rule, it keeps  all records from the left table and join records from the right table. 
Premium and CompanyLine column belongs to ProductionReportMetrics table.
I tried to use INNER JOIN's as well,but the same result.

Comment: Tim, are you saying no duplicates because NetRate_QuoteID column is unique? If I just retrieve `SUM(Premium) from ProductionReportMetrics` I got $11,000,000. But after I do those joins, my premium is much much higher. And I dont understand why

Comment: What are the relations of the joins between your tables? Are they all one-to-one? If any of these join is a one-to-many, you have a potential duplicate created there.

Comment: I just did one by one, and everything was ok until I brought the column `Description` in my query. I am assuming multiple `Description` have the same `LocationID`. I will attach a picture

Comment: @Oleg, Can we we a quick typed example of what you would like your result set to be?  Just use the first one or two types, like "Carpentry - interior" and/or "Concrete Construction (Except Silo Erection)"

Comment: Desirable result would be:

`Description                   ClassCode                  Premuim         Month`
`Carpentry - Interior        91341                   33000.00    1`
`Concrete Construction 91560                           250.00           2`
`Contractors               91580+                33000.00            3`

Comment: Sorry, I dont know how to make it look like a table in a Comment.

Comment: You would be best off adding some `create table` scripts along with some `insert` statements to populate them with data (Ideally in an SQLFiddle) and then provide a desired result.  If you do that, you will get an answer very quickly.

Comment: Looks like you have a few cartesian joins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like DVT basically hit on the answer.  The only reason you would get different amounts(i.e. duplicated rows) as a result of a join is that one of the joined tables is not a 1:1 relationship with the primary table.
I would suggest you do a quick check against those tables, looking for table counts.

```
    --this should be your baseline count
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM ProductionReportMetrics
    GROUP BY MONTH(prm.EffectiveDate),
        prm.NetRate_QuoteID

    --this will be a check against the first joined table.  
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote Q
    WHERE QuoteID IN
        (SELECT NetRate_QuoteID 
            FROM ProductionReportMetrics
            GROUP BY MONTH(prm.EffectiveDate),
                prm.NetRate_QuoteID)
```

Basically you will want to do a similar check against each of your joined tables.  If any of the joined tables are part of the grouping statement, make sure they are also in the grouping of the count check statement.  Also make sure to alter the WHERE clause of the check count statement to use the join clause columns you were using.
Once you find a table that returns the incorrect number of rows, you will have your answer as to what table is causing the problem.  Then you will just have to decide how to limit that table down to distinct rows(some type of aggregation).
This advice is really just to show you how to QA this particular query.  Break it up into the smallest possible parts.  In this case, we know that it is a join that is causing the problem, so take it one join at a time until you find the offender.

Comment: I just broken down into smallest parts. The last table in a `JOIN NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote_Locat_Liabi` is the problem. Different `LocationID` have many `ClassCode` and `Description`. What are my options here?

Comment: ShooterMcGavin... baseline query gave me 15,958 records and the second query gave me 14,734 records

Comment: It sounds like the last table needs to be limited in some way before joining it back to the main query.  Do we know a certain ClassCode or Description to limit those records to every time or does that even matter? Could we just get the first listed record for that regardless of the ClassCode/Description?

INNER JOIN 
 (SELECT * 
  FROM NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote_Locat_Liabi nqI
   JOIN (
    SELECT LocationID, MAX(ClassCode)
    FROM NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote_Locat_Liabi
    GROUP BY LocationID
    ) nqA ON nqA.LocationID = nqI.LocationID
 ) QLL ON QLL.LocationID = QL.LocationID

Comment: Yeah, I think that would work, but where should I exactly put that piece of query? In my  select statement?
Sorry, I am not that long doing sql

Comment: That's ok.  The code should replace your join query on the NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote_Locat_Liabi.  Basically just overwrite the entire join with the Join I provided.  
Please keep in mind, the join I provided will only return the MAX ClassCode from that table for each LocationID.  All other ClassCodes will be ignored.  If that is not correct, we will need to further identify the requirements to know which ClassCode we should be after.

Comment: Could you please look at the query I posted? I am missing something. It says `No column name was specified for column 2 of 'nqA'.
Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 13
No column name was specified for column 38 of 'QLL'.
Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 13`

Comment: I see the problem, my mistake.  In the sub-query where it uses MAX(ClassCode), it needs an alias.   
Also on the join you have to add the ClassCode = part. I've corrected it below.

LEFT JOIN
            (SELECT * FROM NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote_Locat_Liabi nqI 
                JOIN ( SELECT LocationID, MAX(ClassCode) as ClassCode
                FROM NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote_Locat_Liabi 
    GROUP BY LocationID ) nqA 
                    ON nqA.LocationID = nqI.LocationID 
      AND nqA.ClassCode = nqI.ClassCode
   ) QLL ON QLL.LocationID = QL.LocationID

Comment: Sorry man, one more thing, now it says 
`Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
The column 'LocationID' was specified multiple times for 'QLL'.`
I added a picture above

Comment: Ok.  It's my bad again.  The issue is, I'm using a SELECT * at the first level of the sub-query and then getting the LocationID from the lowest level sub-query.  Since LocationID is included in the SELECT* it's being included twice.  Here's another try;
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote_Locat_Liabi nqI 
 JOIN ( SELECT LocationID as LocID, MAX(ClassCode) as ClassCode 
  FROM NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote_Locat_Liabi 
  GROUP BY LocationID ) nqA 
   ON nqA.LocID = nqI.LocationID AND nqA.ClassCode = nqI.ClassCode 
  ) QLL ON QLL.LocationID = QL.LocationID

Comment: Thank you. It gives a result. Looks correct but will make sure with a boss ))
Thank you very much for your time and help.